# prestashop Multi-Store redirect issue: does not redirect without www

Tags: .htaccess, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I have set up multi-store and it works fine except for one detail, let me explain:
I have shop 1:

http://www.shop-one.com

Shop 2:

http://www.shop-two.com

If you go to `http://www.shop-two.com` then everything works ok. However, if you go to `http://shop-two.com` (without www) then you get redirected to `http://www.shop-one.com`
That's obviously a big problem as it is likely some visitors will omit the www.

This is the post I have to find into PrestaShop posts. Here is the URL :

https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/233117-solved-multi-store-redirect-issue-does-not-redirect-without-www/

and my problem is the same exactly above post.

After reading all thread I have added this code

```
  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
      RewriteEngine On
      RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
      RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
      </IfModule>
```

into my htaccess file but , it's not resolved my problem.

Here are my domains:

```
  ecopelletstoves.com
  gardenfurniturefrance.com
  gardenfurnitureportugal.com
```

These all domains going to redirect to this domain :

http://www.gardenfurniturespain.com/

and this is my default shop
    http://www.gardenfurniturespain.com/

If I used it with www it's working fine. I am using multistore shop with PrestaShop.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add both [www.shop-two.com](http://www.shop-two.com) and [shop-two.com](http://shop-two.com) to the desired shop URL's.

Any other subdomain/URL pointing to the server will redirect to default shop.

Comment: URL pointing to the server already , just main shop directory they all following . anyway thanks